# Career implications of being in a mostly contractor team?

Tags: new-job

I am a relatively junior developer (2 years of experience) who through a combination of turnover and management not wanting to shell out for lower level staff (they pay our team lead a ton and one senior, but not everyone else) is now on a team that is nearly exclusively contractors and the company is not hiring more but is hiring more overseas contractors.

My problem is that as the only technical employee on the project, my time is relegated to mostly screening code, commenting on code, and directing contractors on what to work on next (as the project manager is not technical, so I had do create the flow diagrams and set validation requirements and such)

I also don't get any meaningful technical mentorship as I am "managing" these contractor people, so they turn to me for answers on specs and requirements.

I have been transitioned to a glorified mail clerk. Is there a decent way to spin this on my resume so I can get out of here?

Comment: Tech lead?  You are moving up, weird you consider that being a mail clerk.

Comment: You may not want that position, but it's somewhat to your advantage actually...

Comment: I see no problem here, what are you saying?  (a) it's utterly normal that teams have many/most contractors.  (b) your "mail clerk" comment is bizarre, you're basically the "architect" or "team tech lead".  It's hard to see what more you could want form a position?  Get more money, and then leave and get more money.

Comment: @Fattie Possibly in your field (banking IIRC) but most companies do NOT hire a ton of contractors.  As for whether its advantageous-  what does OP want to do with his career?  If he wants to manage or product/project manage, its a good position.  If he wants to be an architect/programmer, he's not really advancing in those skills unless he's architecting what the contractors do, which it doesn't sound like.

Answer (score 7):

Glorified mail clerk? That sounds almost like management experience to me.

It's also increasingly common. You're likely to see this elsewhere as well, so it's not like it's invaluable experience. I would maybe put this on your resume along the lines of managing contractors or remote contractors or something.

Comment: Yes.  It is getting more popular too.  Instead of having a team in-house, they basically only trust the employees who oversee teams of contractors.  There are tax and overhead advantages to doing this, and you're the one trusted person to make the project quality, as the other workers won't have to maintain any messes they make.  Offically, they probably won't call you team lead, because that could mean "promotion" which means more pay; but, you're basically doing that job.

Comment: Aside from overhead and tax advantages, departments may have *budget* to pay contractors, but not *headcount* to hire employees... there's set limits in many businesses where in order to permanently 'hire' someone or open a new position, people as far up as the owner may have to be involved... where as if they have the money to pay a contractor they may be able to just rubber stamp it through

Comment: You are right, they create budgets earmarked for different kinds of workers; but, the reason they have a contractor budget is because often the contractors are often cheaper in the long run.  If they weren't, then the company would prefer to hire full time.  This company (like many) is trying to hedge their bets that the "brain drain" of the contractors leaving won't be 100% becuase they have one full time employee on the team, and that the full time employee will uphold quality (because he's not leaving).

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, product owner or team leader would work well on duties you described

Project manager can also fit, but less obviously

Put special emphasis on managing remote, multi time zone team you will be snatched :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to ask your boss for a new title to reflect this.  It would more accurately describe what you are doing, is free to the company, and might be useful for both internal and external job changes.

Comment: The big thing to keep an eye on is that right now it sounds like you are managing a group of contractors. This could change to a 100% contract group (meaning you'd be out).